# Html over background margins

Tags: html, css, margins

I currently have a rhombus as a image on my display.
I'm trying to get text to show over it, but amy html I put in goes to the bottom of the image.

Is there a way to get my html to show on/in the rhombus?
    `

```
    .rhomb {
         -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
          width: 80px;
          height: 80px;
          margin: 250px 130px 0 450px;
          padding: 180px;
          border: none;
          font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: yellow;
          -o-text-overflow: clip;
          text-overflow: clip;
          background: #1abc9c;
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
          transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
          transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
}
```

Comment: Will you share your `html` code too? Or just create a Fiddle ?

Comment: Try to write you question more clear, expecialy the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works...just put the text inside the `.rhomb` div

```css
.rhomb {
         -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
          width: 80px;
          height: 80px;
          margin: 250px 130px 0 450px;
          padding: 180px;
          border: none;
          font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: yellow;
          -o-text-overflow: clip;
          text-overflow: clip;
          background: lightgray;
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
          transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
          transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="rhomb">
    HEY IM SOME TEXT INSIDE THE RHOMBUS
</div>
```

if you want the text to be aligned to the screen (not aligned with the rhombus rotation) use this:

```css
.rhomb {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 250px 130px 0 450px;
    padding: 180px;
    border: none;
    font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background: lightgray;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
    transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
}
.rhomb div{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg)   ;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg)   ;
}
```

```html
<div class="rhomb">
    <div>HEY IM SOME TEXT INSIDE THE RHOMBUS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this responsive? I'd like for the rhombus to size down if the screen gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code it works fine just simply put text within the div.

> ```
> <div class="rhomb">
>  Text
> </div>
> ```